# How do I display a MultiIndex object of a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I had a data frame jobs_2 which has many columns, amongst which are 'city' and 'state'.

From jobs_2 I created a new data frame ‘jobs_2i’ where state and city are set as indices of jobs_2.

For that I used the code:

```
jobs_2i = jobs_2.set_index(['state', 'city'])
```

I now need to use an appropriate property of data frames to display the MultiIndex object of jobs_2i, but I am unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but here is a quick example of using a MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['state', 'city'])
df.loc['California']  # Gets me everything with state is california
df.loc[('California', 'Los Angeles')]  # Gets me everything in Los Angeles, CA
```

Is that what you were looking to solve? Otherwise, can you try and give me an example?